# Showing Information on button click

Tags: php

I am making a test project in PHP. I want to show some information on click of button named 'View Details'. But there are 3 different buttons like this. Each are showing different information. I want to manage like user can see only one information at a time. Can Any one help me?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: have you tried javascript or jquery?? Both makes easy that you want>>

Comment: If the question is "Can Any one help me?" - yes, a lot of people can help you here, if you describe what the actual problem is.

Comment: @jogesh_p Thanks Dear... But I haven't much more idea about jquery. so will you please give me some code for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will manage flag to show/hide your information.

e.g if any one click on view details button you have set flag=1 in javascript and check this flag on another button click if is already 1 then does not display any information.

Comment: yes I know that but the problem is that in page the sapce of the hidden content is shown blank. I want to remove that space when another button will be clicked

Comment: Ok you can assign blank like document.getElementById('div').innerHTML=''; OR document.getElementById('div').style.display='none';

Comment: To show content document.getElementById('div').style.display='';

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wrapper div say "resultsDiv" and display the response (ajax) from your php file to this DIV. So that only one information is seen at a time, like:

```
//First ajax call on first button click,
$.ajax({
...
..
success: function(resp) {
 $("#resultsDiv").html('');  //clear the DIV html
 $("#resultsDiv").html(resp); //place the response
}
});
//Second ajax call on second button click,
$.ajax({
...
..
success: function(resp) {
 $("#resultsDiv").html('');
 $("#resultsDiv").html(resp);
}
});
//more ajax calls
//your div that will hold response of ajax call on various button clicks
<div id="resultsDiv"></div>
```

Did you mean something like this

Comment: Now just check image that I have uploaded.... In this I want to display the the content in a particular <fieldset> of particular button. I think now you will got what I want to do...

Comment: And another problem is that in page the sapce of the hidden content is shown blank. I want to remove that space when another button will be clicked